# Bundle with react js

Tags: reactjs, bundle

I am a beginner with reactjs so I start to create a site, I do all installations, I installed Webpack to generate automatically  the bundle.js all it works well and the file bundle.js is well generated but nothing that posster on the index page (page index is empty) and there are also no errors on the console. Somewhat help me please

Comment: Please write in English. Ecrivez en anglais s'il vous plait.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO. To get started with reactJS you can use the predefined boiler plates which have all configuration setup. for example you can use our react boiler plate https://github.com/Codebrahma/react-redux-boilerplate

Comment: bundle.js:357 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Router (created by App)
    in App

Comment: bundle.js:7111 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at new Router (bundle.js:7111)
    at bundle.js:19577
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:19358)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (bundle.js:19576)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (bundle.js:19562)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:19470)
    at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:3062)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (bundle.js:18908)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (bundle.js:17064)

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit messy to get up & running if you're not experienced with these technologies and how module bundling in Webpack works.

This is exactly why Facebook created the "create-react-app" solution so that you can get running without any build config and focus on creating the app that you're after instead. You can use it and "eject" to a custom setup anytime and see how they've done it:

[create-react-app by Facebook](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

Here is a guide that you can follow along to create a simple config build:

[Setup a React Environment Using webpack and Babel](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setup-a-react-environment-using-webpack-and-babel)

You can also check out some of the other solutions that the community offers, here is a list of 143 React starter projects:

[Find your perfect React starter project](http://Find%20your%20perfect%20React%20starter%20project)